# Проблема с кодировкой при отображении текста

Tags: javascript, html, кодировка

Есть input для чтения файла `jade`:

```
input#upload.(type='file', accept="text/xml, .csv")
```

javascript:

```
var file = document.getElementById('upload').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e){
     var file = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

В скрипте получаю строку:

```
"mail;name;Ð¢ÐµÑÑ"
```

Последнее слово - "Тест". Как исправить проблемы с кодировкой? И javascript и html страница в кодировке "UTF-8".

Comment: Если хотите текст, почему используете `readAsBinaryString` вместо `readAsText`?

Comment: Peter Olson, спасибо) А не возникнет проблем, если пользователи будут подгружать файлы с разными кодировками?

Comment: Я не уверен. Я думаю, что скорее всего, да, возникнет проблем, но лучше пробовать, чем гадать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.